# Hide iOs status bar with Sencha

Tags: ios, sencha-touch

I'm writing an iPad app using Sencha Touch 2 and I need my app to be fullscreen. I added the

```
viewport:{
    autoMaximize:true,
}
```

to my app.js but I still have the status bar. Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else asked this question four days ago on the [Sencha Touch forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234975-Hiding-iPad-Status-Bar-in-Native-apps):

Asker:

> Hello, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to hide the black iPad status bar on Sencha Touch 2 native packaged apps. I've done it before when creating an xcode UIWebView but it would be fantastic if this was possible via the Sencha Touch native packager.
>
> Thanks!

Response (from Senior Forum Manager):

> I don't think this is currently possible.

So, I have to say, sorry but I don't think its possible. Maybe someone on the forum has a "hack" or trick for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it in your plist to "statusBar Initally hidden".